# LabView web server cannot access

Tags: webserver, labview

I would like to create the web server from LabVIEW VI but when i did the VI interface part was missing (that part is just blank and gave error). I tried to look for the solution from the internet and some says that plugins are missing so I downloaded and installed all plugin as suggest (windows silverlight and LabVIEW run time) but the result still the same. 
Anybody have another suggestion?

(When i did this i followed this link: http://www.ni.com/white-paper/4791/en/)

Thanks,
Tanja

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Latest version of Microsoft silverlight. After this make sure you open your interface via Internet explorer. Chrome would not like to open silverlight GUI.

Comment: i already installed the latest version of Microsoft siverlight and also tried to use internet explorer but still not success.